# Turtlebot ISO is AMD64

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the iso that is available on the Turtlebot setup page is labeled AMD64.
Are there any images available for Intel 86s?

It would be nice if there was an image for a 32bit machine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12218/turtlebot-iso-is-amd64/) by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ISO is really intended for exactly the laptop that is shipping from vendors. If someone wants to contribute a 32-bit ISO, some instructions can be found here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/isogenerator

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-12-05**:
OK thanks :)